# form into a fancybox and fancybox into an iframe is not submiting

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form opening with fancybox into an iframe(pg3_1.php). The form is not submiting the info.

Index.html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

```html
<body>  
    <div class="span12">
        <b>Corredor Seleccionado:</b><br>
        <iframe width="820" height="615" src="pg3_1.php" frameborder="0" name='rightside'></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

The pg3_1.php page is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#abrirdiv').fancybox();
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();               
});
```

```html
<body>
    <a href='form.php' class='fancybox fancybox.ajax'><button class='btn btn-success' style='float: right;' id='boton'><i class='icon-plus'></i> <strong>Button</strong></button></a>
</body>
```

And the form (form.php):

```js
function askforsendingform() {
    if (confirm('are you sure?')) {
        document.form.submit()
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <?php
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" role="form" name="form">
        <div class="span5">
            <label for="time">time</label>
            <input type="time" name="initialtime" value="">
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default" onclick="askforsending()">
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
        } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
            $time = $_POST['initialtime'];
            $sql="INSERT INTO tabletime (time) VALUES ('$time')";
            mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
</body>
```

I don't get do submit and no error is showing in the console, thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to close elseif brace before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Kindly used data- tags and fetch it from iframe using jQuery.